# How to pause python's for loop until Arduino responds

Tags: python, arduino, teensy

I've created a python code (Tkinter GUI) that is supposed to communicate with Arduino via serial communication.

I have a table that I need to send over, column by column.
but before I send the next column I need to wait for the Arduino to finish processing the previous one.

Here is a code that iterates through the table:

```
def send():

    for row in rows:
        for col in row:
            print(col.get()),
        print(" ")
```

Here is how the table was created:

```
rows = []

for i in range(1, 20):

    cols = []
    for j in range(6):
        e = Entry(secondFrame, relief=RIDGE, justify=CENTER)
        e.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky=NSEW)
        #e.insert(END, '%d.%d' % (i, j))
        e.insert(END, '-')
        cols.append(e)
    rows.append(cols
```

Comment: theres nothing here with serial ... how does the arduino program signal that it has finished processing the previous column?

Answer (score 1):

the arduino will surely signal somehow once it is ready for more data ... for example perhaps it sends a `'>'` ... ill assume you have a `ser` variable that is an instance of `pyserial.Serial` (since you didnt include any thing indicating a serial connection)

```
ser.write(columnData)
response = ser.read_until(">")
print("Probably can send the next column...")
```